# How can I turn all red pixels white quickly in an image in R?

Tags: r, image, image-processing, pixel

I am trying to selectively turn all red/pink pixels in to white (hence, deleting them). There is a pink/red grid in the background of ECG images I'm working with, and I want to delete that (note: turning the whole image grayscale will not work).

I've ended up writing a laborious for loop that finds all "dark" pixels (IE R < 0.1, G < 0.1, B < 0.1) and then turns those black (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), leaving all other pixels white (1.0, 1.0, 1.0). Here is that code:

```
DropGrid <- function (im, b.thresh = 0.1)
{
    black.pix <- which (im[,,1,1] < b.thresh & im[,,1,2] < b.thresh & im[,,1,3] < b.thresh)
    black.X <- rep (NA, length(black.pix))
    black.Y <- rep (NA, length(black.pix))

    for (i in 1:length(black.pix))
    {
        black.X[i] <- as.integer(black.pix[i] %% nrow(im))
        black.Y[i] <- as.integer(black.pix[i] / nrow(im)) + 1
    }

    im.alter <- imfill (x = nrow(im), y = ncol(im), z = 1, val = c(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0))

    for (i in 1:length(black.pix))
    {
        im.alter[black.X[i], black.Y[i], 1, ] <- c (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    }

    return (im.alter)
}
```

In this function, im is the original ECG image and im.alter is the desired image. The problem is that this takes about 60 seconds per image which is desperately slow.

Is there a faster way to mess with all pixels in an image that fit some condition?

I'm using the `imager` to load images. The results of str(im) are:

```
'cimg' num [1:1208, 1:927, 1, 1:4] 0.796 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Here is a representative image. I want to quickly remove the pink/red grid:
[image]

Thank you so much!

Comment: Post `str(im)` and a small portion of that object (probably a matrix.) With R's vectorized code  you probably can do this without a loop. I don't think your definition of red is a particularly good one. Lots of no-red colors would meet that logical test.

Comment: Which package are you using to load an the image into R?

Comment: Hi, thank you- I am using imager to load/manipulate images and I posted the results of str(im) above. I agree, that's a bad definition of red, but once I figure out how to use R's vectorized code to manipulate (all pixels meeting condition X), I can then figure out the best definition for "condition X". Thanks again for any help

Comment: Can you share a representative image?

Answer (score 2):

If I make a little test image in the Terminal with **ImageMagick** by taking a single black, a pink and a red pixel, placing them in a row and resizing, I get this:

```
magick xc:black xc:pink xc:red +append -resize 400x100 image.png
```

[image]

If I then set the *"fill colour"* to white and say I want all pixels within 10% of pink to become white:

```
magick image.png -fill white -fuzz 10% -opaque pink result.png
```

[image]

If I make that 25% to broaden the range around my target colour:

```
magick image.png -fill white -fuzz 25% -opaque pink result.png
```

[image]

I don't use `R` but I believe there is an **ImageMagick** package for it that you could use to implement a version of the above. As I said, I have no idea about `R` but these seem to be the resources you might need:

[Resource 1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html)
[Resource 2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/index.html)

Or you can use `system()` in `R` and *"shell out"* to directly use the command-line code above. I guess that will look something like:

```
system("magick image.png -fill white -fuzz 25% -opaque pink result.png")
```

It takes milliseconds to process the image.

---

If `pink` isn't very good at targeting the colour you want to remove, you can always run a *"colour dropper"* (or maybe called *"eye dropper"*) over your image (it's called *"Digital Color Meter"* on macOS) and identify the RGB colour you want to remove, then specify its RGB coordinates to **ImageMagick** instead of guessing `pink` as the target by name. So, say your colour is `rgb(255,0,128)` like this:

[image]

You can use RGB coordinates:

```
magick image.png -fill white -fuzz 25% -opaque "rgb(255,0,128)" result.png
```

Or hex:

```
magick image.png -fill white -fuzz 25% -opaque "#ff0080" result.png
```

---

I see you have added a sample image now, so you could use:

```
magick FNr0h.png -fill white -fuzz 20% -opaque "rgb(250,160,170)" result.png
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

thank you - I read your answer, researched using magick in R, and found the following code to work perfectly on all sample images:

```
im <- magick::image_read ("sample_image.png")
im.proc <- image_transparent (im, "pink", 20)
magick::image_write (im.proc, "processed_image.png", format = "png", flatten = TRUE)
```

I can then read in the processed_image.png with whatever image library I want, and the red/pink colors will have been removed. Thank you all again.

Comment: Cool - well done! And thank you for sharing back with the Stack Overflow community so  other folk can see how to do it in future.